# Парсинг строки Bash

Tags: bash, sed

Имеется код:

```
#!/bin/bash
inputfile=$1
while read LINE; do
    ip=$(echo $LINE | awk -v rx='((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9]{1,2})\\.){3}(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9]{1,2})' 'match($0,rx){print substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)}')
    linewithoutip=$(echo $LINE | sed 's/$ip//')
    echo $linewithoutip
done < $inputfile
```

Его задача - удалять IP из каждой строки файла, и выводить строки без ip в терминал. Почему-то удаления IP из строки не происходит.

Содержимое файла, который подаётся на вход:

```
10.10.10.10@log10:pass10
11.11.11.11@log11;pass11
12.12.12.12 log12:pass12
13.13.13.13 log13;pass13
log14:pass10@14.14.14.14
log15;pass11@15.15.15.15
log16:pass12 16.16.16.16
log17;pass13 17.17.17.17
```

Answer (score 0):

Решением было заменить одинарные кавычки на двойные в строке:

```
linewithoutip=$(echo $LINE | sed 's/$ip//')
```

Должно получиться так:

```
linewithoutip=$(echo $LINE | sed "s/$ip//")
```